# Dilemma of choosing either to hash or encrypt passwords

Tags: encryption, hash, passwords

After reading some posts and articles online, it seems that most, if not all, people suggest using some sort of hashing algorithm for keeping a user's password safe, since you cannot unhash it, which is good, but that's where I begin to have a problem with my situation.

Right now I am in the early stages of modifying the way we secure our users' passwords. We currently store the **hashed** passwords in our MySQL DB using **Sha512**. With my current understanding, although hashes may be secure in the sense that they cannot be reverse (or at least not so easily), it is also insecure in that there are possible collisions, since a hash has a fixed length no matter the size of the original input, which limits the number of possible hashes, causing a possible Pidgeon Hole problem.

Now comes another part that I have a problem with, especially for my case.

I am trying add some features to our users' password where the user cannot enter a new password if it is too similar to, say, their last three passwords. Ex: if their last password was `password1234` and their new one is `xxxpasswordxxx`, then it would fail. However, from my understanding, it is not possible for me to add this feature since I have no way of unhashing their previous passwords to check if any substring in their old passwords are in their new password. This brings me to the whole encryption/decryption part.

I have been looking at **AES 128** using a **CBC** encryption mode and it seems like a solid choice, since I don't really care much for parallelization in the encrypted portion. Additioanlly, by using an encyption route instead of a hashing route, I can actually do that check to see if their last three passwords are similar to their current one! BUT, there is the whole problem of being able to see the users' plain text password in the first place.

Additionally, I have been trying to think of a way to use unique keys for every single password without storing it in our DB because I feel that is way too insecure. I could just use a static randomly key for ALL passwords, but I am not sure if that is a good idea either, even if I use unique IVs for all the passwords.

So to sum up my situation is this:
I want to be able to prevent the user from entering a password similar to their old one's, in addition to actually improving the security of our password storage. From the knowledge I have at the moment, I can either continue storing the passwords as a hash, but I won't be able to do the similar password check OR I can encrypt the passwords instead, which is something that is frowned upon.

I am clearly not an expert in this and I know for a fact I need to do some more research, but I want to make sure I am starting in the right direction.

Comment: Why prevent the user from entering a password similar to their old one ?

Comment: @BilalBOUTAYA We have added a feature where after X amount of days they must change their password. It is totally pointless, imo, to let them change their password from, say, "password123" to "password1234". Although it is a VALID change in that they are different, they are still too similar, which could be a weakness.

Comment: It is totally pointless to force the user to change their password in the first place. What that results in is user writing down their password in plain form on a note next to the monitor. Or cause them to use simpler and simpler passwords (not really what you want either)

Comment: Forcing password changes at an often recurring interval is [counter-productive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_policy#Password_duration): *The benefit of password expiration, however, is debatable. [...] This policy can often **backfire**. Some users find it hard to devise "good" passwords that are also easy to remember, so if people are required to choose many passwords because they have to change them often, they end up using much **weaker passwords**; the policy also encourages users to **write passwords down**.*

Comment: @Andreas thanks for the link for my claim :D

Comment: @Andreas You do have a very good point and I do agree with that, but would it still be safe if they barely changed their password, even if they are forced to change it, say every 3 months (something that our clients requested themselves)

Comment: Forcing a password change prevents users from using the same password across all of their sites and accounts. I don't want an attacker able to commit fraud on my customer's banking site because their password was compromised at another site that I don't have control over.

Comment: @AlexR Forcing a password change doesn't prevent that. If all sites require frequent changes, then a dumb user would just change all of them, so they still only have to remember one password, which means you have gained *nothing*. Besides, there is nothing you can do about stupid users who don't learn good password management. If they use same password on all sites, that's their problem, not yours.

Comment: I would say that it becomes "my problem" when I'm fiscally responsible for the fallout, like the example i gave for a bank. I agree with you that there may be the case that every few months when their sites have all finished forcing a password change at different dates throughout the year, there may be an overlapping period where they are all the same.

Comment: You are mixing a few things up @AlexR Your first job is preventing a breach of your system. But if you fail to do that your second job is making sure the attacker cannot easily gain access to a complete list of all username / email-address / password tuples. In the "bank example" the bank is responsible for the money lost on its site with faked transaction as a result of the breach, etc. But if the attacker manages to match *some* emails/users with their password it is not your job to make sure the user with the same email address does not use the same password for his email and facebook login

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding the second paragraph: hash collisions are **absolutely NOT** a problem. For which attack scenario do you think that is a problem? You should really stop throwing buzzwords around, especially regarding security.

You are partially right that your feature idea would fail. And that is a good think because the idea is bad. Why do you want that "feature" - it will only annoy users and cause people try to circumvent your restrictions using numbers at the end including the month or some other incrementing from version to version.

And encrypting passwords is bad - period.
As soon as *you* can decrypt them, an attack can as well - end of story.

---

Personal experience of pretty much the scenario you are describing: The client has a tool where you are forced to change the password every 2 months, I am currently at `"password"10`. I am doing exactly what everybody is warning about when forcing password changes every X months - simply altering the same password piece by piece. I have a very good password (15+ characters, upper and lower case, numbers, special chars) plus a system for choosing a password for whatever site I am setting an account up for. Forcing me to change my password breaks my "system" because now I can no longer generate the password in my head over and over again because the outcome will not match what the site has forced me to set up after the first two months. If the site would start introducing some password similarity restrictions I would probably start writing them down.

Comment: Well, this may not be considered an actual attack scenario, but if there are collisions, then couldn't a person type in a different password for a user and gain access to their account? Although I do agree that it will annoy them, I have read an article suggesting that frequent password changes may just cause the user to barely modify their passwod. Is it really not that much of a difference if they slightly modify it, say by adding an additional number vs changing it completely?

Comment: @swagantiswag first: yes, that is theoretically possible, but the alternative hash-wise for the password "password" is probably something like "sodufbaosidfbaiousfnaosid nfasifnafoiugn r9uteh5t ß9sgers9h", not really a probable user input as a second password guess. The probability of entering a phrase that hashes to the same value is sooo low you do not really have to worry about it. I do not understand your second question.

Comment: @swagantiswag The *probability* of a collission is so small it is really non-existent. 1 / 2^512 means that if you run 1 TRILLION attempts per second, it will still take longer than the current age of the universe to find a collision.

Comment: @Andreas Sorry, my second question is this: is it more "secure" if the user   makes a big change to their password or is a minor change enough?

Comment: @swagantiswag that depends on what your attack "knows", if he has the old plain text password at hand he can alter that password and guess the slightly changed one probably quite quickly. If the attacker only has the hashes the difference between the passwords does not make a difference. What exactly are you trying to protect against? Stop adding "random" security features without a very good reason - they might do more harm than good.

Comment: @luk2302 Ok. Sorry, I honestly thought that making a bigger password change would be more secure compared to just, say, modifying one letter/number. I now see that my original idea is wrong and I will change it.

Comment: @swagantiswag You are welcome - in terms of hashing appending a single character is as "secure" as changing the entire string, that is basically what those hashing algorithms are designed for, massive change in the output for minimal change in the input. And is it a good thing that you asked before making such a change.

Comment: @luk2302 Ok I am very glad that I know that now! Although I did spend quite some time looking up the different types of encryption algorithms and their pros and cons, I feel like I still gained something from this. Glad I got to learn something new today ^_^

Answer (score 4):

Why not keep using hashing, but require that the user enters his or her old password when changing to a new password, that way you can authenticate the old password to authorize the password change, then compare the plain-text versions of both for similarity before proceeding with the change?

Comment: Probably the only valid way which does not directly weaken the security of the system.

Comment: I actually have already implemented that to our system, but I wanted to see if I could make requirements to change their password a little bit more strict. However, I am getting the feeling that what I originally wanted to do seems have the opposite output of what I wanted...

Comment: Well if you have both their old password and their new password in plain text, then you can do any type of comparisons and processing you want. it could be as strict or as lax as you want.

Answer (score 4):

when you keep hashed passwords, you can not check for similar passwords, but you could prevent them from reusing a password they used before. By keeping the old (hopefully salted!) passwords, you can compare hash(new_password + old_salt[i]) with the salted_hash[i] of the old password. If they are the same, the user is reusing an old password.

I totally agree with the others that hash collisions are not a problem. You are planning to use SHA512, that is 512 bits of randomness the attacker has to compete with. The only way you could break that is by using [rainbow tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) and you protect yourself against them using the salted hashes (i.e. even if the password is the same, the salted hash will result in different hashes; it is not a problem if the attacker gets to know both the salt and the hash, so you can store salt + salted_hash in one location).

For security reasons I'd ditch the "similar password" thing altogether. If the attacker gets a bunch of passwords, changes are that there are a lot of bad passwords in your database. Using heuristics and dictionary attacks he will have a good change to guess your encryption key --> immediately unlocks all passwords of all users.

**The only safe way for passwords is if the operator of the system storing them cannot recover them either.** Anything else is just the next 0-day bug waiting to be exploited.

Answer (score 3):

> currently store the hashed passwords in our MySQL DB using Sha512

SHA-512 is *too fast*. Any attacker gaining access to your password hashes can very quickly run their password guesses through your hash. You need a slow algorithm so each guess takes them thousands of times longer. But as you need to hash these passwords too, you need to choose a value that won't overload your system, or arguably even worse, test your users' patience. Use either [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) (on its own) or [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) in combination with your SHA-512 (although SHA-1 HMAC is more than enough).

> it is also insecure in that there are possible collisions

The collision resistance of SHA-512 is not a problem until you are approaching 2<sup>256</sup> users within your system. As there are not even close to that number of people on the planet, I can safely say your system will be fine.

> Dilemma of choosing either to hash or encrypt passwords

If you need a reason to go with the former, have a look at the [details of the Adobe breach](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2013/11/04/anatomy-of-a-password-disaster-adobes-giant-sized-cryptographic-blunder/). They were encrypting passwords instead of hashing. TLDR; disaster. If your system is even moderately sized, you don't want anything like this being presented by the media regarding your system. Do things properly - use PBKDF2 or bcrypt - that way you are looking after your users using industry accepted methods and cannot then be criticised for your password storage scheme.

> by using an encryption route instead of a hashing route, I can
>   actually do that check to see if their last three passwords are
>   similar to their current one

Well since the user will (hopefully) be entering their previous password as an additional authentication check in order to change their password, you could compare their passwords at this point as you will have them both in cleartext. For example

```
old password != new password
lowercase'd letters in old password != lowercase'd letters in new password
adding up all numbers in new password > adding up all numbers in old password + 2 || adding up all numbers in new password < adding up all numbers in old password - 2
```

And maybe some other rules you wish to define to prevent password similarity. If these rules are applied between changes from the first password to the second, and then the second password to the third, the user may get used to your rules and may be less likely to make their third  password too similar to their first. You could also keep a password history table storing the bcrypt hashes of their previous X passwords (e.g. four), and do an absolute comparison to ensure they are not switching back to one they have previously used. I wouldn't keep more than four just in case any of their previous passwords are weak enough to crack and have been reused on other sites, because any breach on your system could potentially expose them, and also as mentioned checking these will be a slow process. You could however, going forward ensure that the user doesn't choose any password that has been involved in any breach by loading common passwords into a blacklist on your system.

Encryption of passwords is a bad idea, and the security benefit of fuzzy matching on all previous passwords does not outweigh the security risk of having two-way encryption active (in my opinion).

Answer (score 2):

To keep password in a secret manner, you have to hash the password plus a salt.

For each user, you randomly choose a salt, you keep in database the salt for each user.
You store in database hash(password+salt).

When you have to check user's password, just add the salt, hash both and check against database.
If a user change the password, you can change the salt as well.

Aftewhile, you may choose an algorithm or another depending of the security level, SHA2 seems to be a good start.